# How to created a nested dictionary with list values?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I have the follow two queryset:

```
opus = Work_Music.objects.filter(composerwork__person=self.kwargs['pk'], level=0).order_by('date_completed')
event = LifeEvent.objects.filter(person=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('date_end')
```

The first pulls the work of a composer and the second pulls his life events.

I want to create a nested dictionary: The first level is keyed by year. The second level has two keys 'work' and 'life'. It should be a list of values because there could be multiple work and events in a given year.

I have written following:

```
    # timeline = defaultdict(list)
    timeline = dict()
    for o in opus:
        if o.date_comp_f not in timeline:
            timeline[o.date_comp_f] = {}
            timeline[o.date_comp_f]['work'] = {}
            timeline[o.date_comp_f]['work'].append(o)
        else:
            timeline[o.date_comp_f]['work'].append(o)
    for e in event:
        if e.date_end_y not in timeline:
            timeline[e.date_end_y] = {}
            timeline[e.date_end_y]['life'] = {}
            timeline[e.date_end_y]['life'].append(e)
        else:
            timeline[e.date_end_y]['life'].append(e)
    timeline = dict(timeline)
```

I also want to sort the first level key in chronological order. How do I do this? I keep getting Key errors.

Comment: Can you provide the models for `Work_Music` and `LifeEvents`?  This is very difficult to visualize without seeing the FK relationships

Answer (score 0):

You were using `{}` when you wanted to use a list?  I'm guessing this was a typo, but here is the fix (with a few simplifications):

```
# timeline = defaultdict(list)
timeline = dict()
for o in opus:
    if o.date_comp_f not in timeline:
        timeline[o.date_comp_f] = {}
        timeline[o.date_comp_f]['work'] = []
    timeline[o.date_comp_f]['work'].append(o)
for e in event:
    if e.date_end_y not in timeline:
        timeline[e.date_end_y] = {}
        timeline[e.date_end_y]['life'] = []
    timeline[e.date_end_y]['life'].append(e)

timeline = dict(timeline)
```

If this doesn't work, (which I assume it doesn't) can you please provide the `Work_Music` and `LifeEvents` models?